# How to prevent the Grails Asset-Pipeline to process .svn files?

Tags: svn, grails, asset-pipeline

**Grails** 2.4 is now using the **Asset Pipeline** for managing and processing static assets in Grails applications instead of the Resources system. This is pretty new and there isn't much doc about it on the internet yet.

How do I configure the asset plugin so that it doesn't uglify and bundle all my `.svn` (Subversion) metadata files?

Comment: If you upgrade to Subversion 1.7 or newer, you will only have a top-level .svn folder, and thus won't run into this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would look at the configuration section of the [documentation](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/guide/configuration.html) where it explains how to setup excludes. I suspect it will be something like the following inside your Config.groovy

```
grails.assets.excludes = ['**/.svn/**']
```

Comment: You are almost there. The correct answer is `["**/.svn/**"]`. If you edit your answer I will mark it as accepted.